# How to count specific value in cells if they are separated with comma e.g. need to count "A" , Cell 1 = A,E, Cell 2 =A,C,F

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to count specific values in multiple cells where values are separated with comma

```
    A       A   A,F A
```

I need to count `'A'` in above example as values in cells are separated by comma.

Comment: `=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"A",""))`

Comment: Thanks Akina. But this count a specific cell where a value is separated by come, but not working on a complete row where multiple cells having specific value separated  by coma

Comment: Nothing prevents using something like `CONCATENATE(A1:F1)` instead of single `A1` in the formula...

Comment: `=COUNTIF(1:1,"*"&"A"&"*")`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- Enter the text you want to count in cell `C52`.
- Formula in cell `D53`:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT((LEN(B53)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B53,$C$52,"")))/LEN($C$52))
  ```
- Fill formula down.

**N.B.**

- Putting value in cell `C52`, makes formula dynamic.
- It's case sensitive.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.